# jquery ui slider does not refresh properly when the step size divides evenly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have a jquery UI range slider with a range of 0-500 and a step size of 50. When I drag the right most edge of the slider to the left it leaves a line to the right hand side of the slider as if it did not repaint properly. I'm using chrome. The code for the example is shown below and I've included a link to the jsfiddle that shows the issue.

If I change the step size to something that does't divide evenly then I don't have this issue. Does anyone know why this is happening?

http://jsfiddle.net/XF4jk/1/

```
<html>
    <body>
      <div id="slider-range"></div>

      <script>
      $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
                step: 50,
        values: [ 0, 500 ]
    });
        $( "#slider-range" ).width(150);
      })();
      </script>

   </body>
</html>
```